# Java difference between two URL Encoded strings

Tags: java, string, encoding, java-me, utf-8

What is the difference between the following two encoded strings?

```
%D0%9E%D0%BA%D0%B6%D1%8D%D0%B7
```

and

```
%26%231055%3B%26%231088%3B%26%231080%3B%26%231074%3B%26%231077%3B%26%231090%3B
```

I am trying to URL Encode the russian text "Привет" into the second encoded string above (the [W3Schools encoder](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) does it correctly), but the URL encoder that I am using keeps giving me the first encoded string above.  I am using [URLUTF8Encoder.java](http://www.w3.org/International/URLUTF8Encoder.java) from the W3 consortium.  I have to use this one as I am working on a mobile platform requiring J2ME.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The URL encoder at w3schools is doing it utterly wrong.  The `%D0%9E%D0%BA%D0%B6%D1%8D%D0%B7` is perfectly valid. That's also what I get when I do

```
String encoded = URLEncoder.encode("Привет", "UTF-8");
```

When I URL-decode the w3schools' answer as follows

```
String decoded = URLDecoder.decode("%26%231055%3B%26%231088%3B%26%231080%3B%26%231074%3B%26%231077%3B%26%231090%3B", "UTF-8");
```

then I get `&#1055;&#1088;&#1080;&#1074;&#1077;&#1090;` which are exactly those Russian characters, but then converted into [XML entities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references) first.

That w3schools site is by the way in no way related to W3 Consortium. See also [w3fools](http://w3fools.com).

Answer (score 3):

Your string "Привет" is encoded as:

```
%D0%9E    
%D0%BA
%D0%B6
%D1%8D
%D0%B7
```

The second string seems to be converted into HTML entities before url-encoding:

```
%26%231055%3B
%26%231088%3B
%26%231080%3B
%26%231074%3B
%26%231077%3B
%26%231090%3B
```

`%26` is `&`, `%23` is `#`, `%3B` is `;`:

```
&#1055;
&#1088;
&#1080;
&#1074;
&#1077;
&#1090;
```